# The execution of the program ends after the input of the char variable in C++

Tags: c++, char

I wrote a program that requests the name of a student and his marks. Everything compiles smoothly but after the execution, the program asks just for the name and than it stops.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    class student{
        public :
        char *name;
        int marks1; int marks2;

        student(char* n, int n1, int n2){
            name=n, marks1=n1, marks2=n2;
        }

        int calc_med(){return (marks1+marks2)/2;}

        void display(){
            std::cout<<name<<"\n The mediane is >> "<<calc_med()<<"\n";
        }
    };

    char *name1;
    std::cout<<"Enter the student's name > ";
    std::cin>>name1;
    int m1;
    std::cout<<"Enter the first mark > ";
    std::cin>>m1;   
    int m2;
    std::cout<<"Enter the second mark > ";
    std::cin>>m2;


    student student1(name1,m1,m2);
    student1.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `name1` has not been allocated.  The `cin>>name1` is sending data to the giggleweeds.

Comment: Side issue: Your class declaration usually shouldn't be inside a function definition. I don't know of a reason off the top of my head why C++ wouldn't allow this, but even if it did, it's at the very least not a good practice.

Comment: I'm with @Chipster . I can think of a few cases where defining a class in a function is a good idea, but this is not one of them. Hibou, this class is now only visible inside `main`. This makes it harder to construct the program with simple function building blocks as all functionality that requires `student` is now forced to be implemented in `main`. This will lead to problems debugging (and with maintenance in production code).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to allocate `name` (or `name1` as it may be).

There are a lot of ways to do this, but the best way is either a) use an `std::string`:

```
std::string name;
```

or b) turn name into an array:

```
char name[BUFFER_SIZE]; // BUFFER_SIZE is some constant
```

**Note**: b) might require some special logic to make sure you don't go past `BUFFER_SIZE`, but I'll leave that up to you to figure out.

Comment: @Hibou You're welcome. If this solved your problem, you can accept this answer by clicking the check mark next to it. Or, you can accept another answer if it was better.

Answer (score 1):

In this part of your code:

```
char *name1;
std::cout<<"Enter the student's name > ";
std::cin>>name1;
```

`name1` is simply a variable that can store an address to a `char` type. If you want to give data to this variable, try allocating some memory to `name1` with this:

```
char *name1 = new char[50];
```

Now, `name1` has a chunk of continuous memory where you can put up to 50 `char` values. `new` will allocate that space, and then give `name1` the address to where that space exists.

Your program is crashing because of undefined behavior when you try to assign data to an undefined address.

EDIT: As someone else noted, `std::string` should be used with `std::cin`, in place of the C-string `char*`, since it does not require memory allocation and is a much safer method. The memory in a `string` is automatically allocated and managed for you, freeing you of the responsibility to create and delete space for a `char` array.

Comment: There is no need for unmanaged dynamic allocation here. A `std::string` or an automatically allocated array  should be used.

Comment: It's more beneficial in this case for the asker to see why their solution doesn't work than to be given an easy solution. I'll add a note to use std::string for best practice.

Comment: This goes a bit beyond ease. You're making this needlessly hard by dumping an unnecessary memory management burden on the asker.

Comment: Memory management is a fundamental c++ concept/practice. I'm not disagreeing that `std::string` should be used, just that there's nothing to be learned by telling them to use a `string`

Comment: The art of memory management includes knowing when and where to dynamically allocate. The problem solved by your example can be resolved with a simple automatically allocated array since the size is known at compile time. There is no need for `new`.

Comment: Again, not disagreeing.

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful :)